# How to install nvidia driver in windows docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am doing a feasibility study on docker(windows container only not linux). I am using Windows Server 1809 with container support in aws, which by default bundled with docker and with g3 instance(using tesla M60).

1)

I know nvidia-docker  is not available for windows. I want to confirm that default docker wont support gpu also, for that i want to install nvidia driver inside docker container. The docker file I am using is shown below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
COPY nvidia-driver-folder nvidia-driver-folder
WORKDIR /nvidia-driver-folder

RUN setup.exe -s -clean -noreboot -noeula
```

The nvidia-driver-folder contains setup.exe for installing driver. I tried  the same command inside container that is

`docker run -it sampleapp cmd`

Then inside container

```
setup.exe -s -clean -noreboot -noeula
```

After that I verified program files inside container, no folder relating to nvidia is created. In normal system(my local machine) even if the gpu is not present, the command I have written above will create a folder NVIDIA Corportation,

2)
Is there any other means to get gpu working inside windows docker container

Please help me for the above two questions

Comment: Did you reach any conclusion?

Comment: I think it is not possible, you have to some how pass your gpu to docker container, like gpu through across VMs which is not possible in windows. I am not sure about these.            Please check this blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/08/13/bringing-device-support-to-windows-server-containers/

Comment: It is possible for Linux, but no trace on how to reproduce it on windows

Linux NVIDIA Container Runtime
https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-container-runtime

Comment: It seems that installing drivers on a container is not required
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/gpu-acceleration

Comment: Dont know about current windows docker solution,need to check  --isolation process --device args. In linux it is possible, also there is nvidia-docker which by default helps us to use gpu in docker